# Remote Login not Working With Curl

Tags: php, authentication, curl

hi i have remote login code and try connect to my Target site but i cant .

```
$url="http://hipfile.com"; 

$postdata = "login=bnnoor&password=########&op=login";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

if (!$result) { 
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
        curl_close($ch); // make sure we closeany current curl sessions 
        die($http_code.' Unable to connect to server. Please come back later.'); 
    } 
echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
```

and login form in site is

```
    <form method="POST" action="http://hipfile.com/" name="FL">

<input type="hidden" name="op" value="login">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://hipfile.com/">
<div class="clear span-5">Username:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="login" value="bnnoor" class="myForm"></div>
Password:&nbsp;<input type="password" name="password" class="myForm">
<input type="image" style="height: 34px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom: 3px; vertical-align: middle;" src="http://hipfile.com/images/login.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://hipfile.com/?op=forgot_pass">Forgot your password?</a><br>

</form>
```

but i cant access my file in site and after start page redirect to login page in site?
plz help me .

Answer (score 1):

A.  Invalid Url

you are using `http://hipfile.com` which would return `HTTP/1.1 500 - Bad Response`

What you need to use is (Note the `/` at the end )

```
 $url = "http://hipfile.com/" ;
```

B. Invalid Referrer

You also need to change `CURLOPT_REFERER` to `http://hipfile.com/login.html`

Answer (score 0):

Just to check, do a GET on the login page and store the set cookie with value. use that cookie along with your post.

Also, send the redirect hidden field along with your post variables

Answer (score 0):

setup `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`, you will keep cookie when next connect

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php