# php curl login not work

Tags: php, curl

Hi i have a problem with the curl. I watched an old post [Remote Login not Working With Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546701/remote-login-not-working-with-curl), but it not work. I followed baba's advice but the code enter in the if statement. Sorry for my bad english. Can anyone help me?

This is the code:

```
$url="http://hipfile.com/";
$urllog="http://hipfile.com/login.html"; 

$postdata = "login=bnnoor&password=########&op=login";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $urllog); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

if (!$result) { 
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
    curl_close($ch); // make sure we closeany current curl sessions 
    die($http_code.' Unable to connect to server. Please come back later.'); 
} 
 echo $result;  
 curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: what error are you getting exactly? whats not working? Are you getting the error: 'Unable to connect to server. Please come back later.'?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are seeing "unable to connect...", then what is the `$http_code`? Can you `var_dumd($result);`?

Comment: the http code is 302 and i get the error Unable to connect to server. Please come back later

Comment: what is the result of `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: `behzad n` issue is different from yours  is different form yours ... its not possible for you to get  `HTTP 302 ` since `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` was set .. can you `var_dump($result)` @Massimo Zampieri

Comment: this is the risult of var_dump: string(0) ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have cookies off for starters. It seems like the site may require them when you login.
The following function is pretty handy for me, the verbose option will display detailed curl
errors and the 'post' option can be set to a post string or an associative array of values 
with the key being the variable/field name with it's value. I also noticed your missing some
post variable from the form on hipfile, this might also be a reason they are denying your
login.

```
fetch('http://www.hipfile.com/');
$options['post'] = 'login=bnnoor&password=########&op=login';
$options['verbose'] = true;
$logged_in_page = fetch('http://www.hipfile.com/login.html',$options);
```

Simple Curl function:

```
function fetch( $url, $z=null ) {
    $ch =  curl_init();
    $useragent = isset($z['useragent']) ? $z['useragent'] : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2';

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, isset($z['post']) );

    if( isset($z['post']) )         curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $z['post'] );
    if( isset($z['refer']) )        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $z['refer'] );
    if( isset($z['ssl']) )          curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
    if( isset($z['ssl']) )          curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    if( isset($z['verbose']) )      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
    if( isset($z['get_header']) )   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
    if( isset($z['header']) )       curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $z['header'] );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  'cookiejarfilepath' );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookiejarfilepath' );

    $result = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: i try your code Adam but it dosen't work and not login. I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: Massimo, when I run this and echo out the $logged_in_page variable I get the front page of hipfile, I'm assuming this is because of the login string not containing real credentials. As I mentioned earlier, you're also missing some post variables in your login string. Hipfile may be checking for those as well. If you're trying to log into a service that is most likely trying to prevent people from coding their way in, then you need to match all the headers sent by your browser as well. Use Firebug or Chrome developer tools to match these exactly.

Comment: I tried to use echo ($logged_in_page) but it doesn't show me the front page. This is the form:                                                      <form method="POST" action="http://hipfile.com/" name="FL">
<input type="hidden" name="op" value="login">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.hipfile.com/">

Comment: <div class="clear span-5">Username:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="login" value="" class="myForm"></div>
Password:&nbsp;<input type="password" name="password" class="myForm">
<input type="image" style="height: 34px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom: 3px; vertical-align: middle;" src="http://hipfile.com/images/login.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://hipfile.com/?op=forgot_pass">Forgot your password?</a><br>

Comment: Can you tell me what are the missing variables pls? I also tried this way: $options['post'] = 'login=bnnoor&password=########&op=login&redirect=http://www.hipfile.com/'; but it still does not work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Open Chrome press F12 and go to the site, under the 'network' tab after you login find the file on the left column that was called to login. Click it and you will see a list of all the post variables and headers sent. http://i.imgur.com/EHtcY.png    Sometimes sites also check the order in which post variable are returned, I have encountered this several times.

Comment: Sorry Adam, i haven't seen your reply. I tryed to put this $options['post'] = 'op=login&redirect=http://hipfile.com/&login=bnnoor&password=########&x=67&y=12'; parameters in my code but it didn't work. Anyway Thanks for your help. I will try to putting coockie in my code.